# ImageViewer isnot working fine codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have a couple of questions regarding image viewer.

1)ImageViewer autoslides isnot working.The imageViewer works initially when the app is first started. But as soon as any other form is opened & then going back to the form containing imageViewer, the autoslide doesnt work.

Code for img viewer auto slide

```
placeholderForTable = (EncodedImage) theme.getImage("placeholderWithAnimate.png");
placeholderForTable = placeholderForTable.scaledEncoded(screenWidth, 30 + (screenWidth * 1 / 3));
BusinessForumImagesConnection bfic = new BusinessForumImagesConnection();
bfic.businessForumImagesConnectionMethod(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultListModel<Image> images;
    if (bfic.response != null) {
        for (Map<String, Object> entrySet : bfic.response) {
            String imgUrl = (String) entrySet.get("imgUrl");
            Image adImage = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholderForTable, imgUrl.substring(0, imgUrl.lastIndexOf(".")), + imgUrl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);
            adsSlideImagesArray.add(adImage);
        }
    }

    ImageViewer imv = new ImageViewer();
    Container adsContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(imv);

    if (adsSlideImagesArray != null) {
        slideIndex = 0;
        images = new DefaultListModel<>(adsSlideImagesArray);
        imv.setImage(images.getItemAt(0));
        imv.setImageList(images);
        imv.setSwipePlaceholder(Image.createImage(100, 100));
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (slideIndex < images.getSize()) {
                    nextImage = (Image) images.getItemAt(slideIndex);
                    if (nextImage != null) {
                        imv.setImage(nextImage);
                    }
                    slideIndex++;
                } else {
                    slideIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        };
        if (uITimer == null) {
            uITimer = new UITimer(r);
        }
        if (uITimer != null) {
            uITimer.schedule(5000, true, f); //5 seconds
        }
    }
});
```

2) Some random images are not always displayed in image viewer. It happens in both simulator & real devices. I have checked if the UrlImage is cached or not in storage. There are all the file saved but some of them are never displayed in image viewer.
Instead of image Viewer, i set the image icon in label and loop them. All the labels have their respective icons, but there is a problem in imageViewer. Code is same as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your timer fires and that no one canceled it.
2. Do you see the placeholder instead of the image? Details like that are essential.

Images that are deeper within the image viewer stack won't be pre-fetched. Notice that `URLImage` wasn't designed for the image viewer and is probably a bad idea for it as `URLImage` resizes the images. We recommend using a download method to get full sized images for the image viewer see this old post: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/image-viewer-from-the-web.html

Comment: System.out.println(nextImage) inside runnable works, so i think timer is working fine but autoslide stops. And for the 2nd question, yeahh i see only placeholder img instead of the actual image(Ps the file is already stored in .cn1 folder) but it is not displayed.

Comment: `URLImage` is special. Again, don't use it for image viewer. I suggest using a debugger and verifying that the timer is animating the view that is currently on the screen.

Comment: thankyou... i solved it. For timer, i made a small mistake that I had initialized uiTimer if it is null. So it runs for the first time and if i comeback to this form from other forms, it doesnt work. Setting uiTimer = null at the start solves the problem.